# Homotopy in $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f: S^1 \to S^1$ be a continuous map, where $S^1$ is the 1-sphere. Prove that if there is an homotopy between $f$ and a constant map, then $f$ has a fixed point.

I don't know how to prove it. I try with the Brouwer fixed point theorem, but I think that it doesn't work in $S^1$

Comment: "There's no fixed point" is the same as "$\forall x, f(x)\neq x$", which means you can divide by $|f(x)-x|$ and the likes of it (such as $|tf(x) - (1-t)x|$)

Answer (score 1):

It's overkill, but this follows straight from the [Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem). In this case the action of $f$ on $H_1(S^1,\Bbb Z)$
takes a generator to zero, so $f_*$ has trace zero on $H_1$, and the
alternating sum of traces equals $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that Brouwer fixed point theorem does not work as it is for $S^1$. You need a continuous map from a closed disk to itself to apply it. What you have for now is a continuous map
$$ H : S^1 \times [0,1] \to S^1 $$
such that $H(-,0) = f$ and $H(-,1) = p$ (for $p$ a point of $S^1$).

Intuitively, you have a cylinder mapped into $S^1$, but all the points of the top of the cylinder are mapped to the same point. So you can squish the top of a cylinder and you end up with a map from a hollow cone (like a birthday hat), which is homeomorphic to the closed disk, to $S^1$ which you can think of as embedded in a disk. Can you now make that formal and finish the argument using Brouwer's theorem?

Comment: I don’t see how the Brouwer theorem helps. No retract seems to me more direct

Comment: @AndresMejia The OP mentioned Brouwer theorem and indicated a feeling that he/she wanted to apply it but without success because not falling in the right hypothesis to do so. I answered precisely that : how to fall in the right conditions. Now there is a continuous map $D\to D$ and Brouwer theorem gives a fixed point; but the image of this map is contained in the boundary $S^1$, so the fixed point is indeed a fixed point of the original map $S^1\to S^1$.  [...]